# ignoring externals when copying

Tags: svn

I want to ignore externals when I copy from source to destination. I tried

```
svn cp --ignore-externals sourcepath destpath
```

but the externals still exist. Any idea how I can make this work?

My source structure is as follows:

```
trunk
   dir1 with sub dir ( need all of this)
   dir2 with sub dir ( each sub dir has a file with svn external prop set)
   dir3 with sub dir ( need all of this)
```

I should be able to get all that I want except externals in my branch with one cp command.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to copy SRC (which has externals) to DEST witouth the externals? I mean, keeping externals on SRC but not having them on DEST?

Answer (score 3):

You can't.

The `svn:externals` is a property ***on*** the file or directory itself. It's as much a part of the file as any actual text in the file. Wanting to copy a directory without the property is like wanting to copy a file without all of the text in that file. It just can't be done.

Also, the `--ignore-externals` flag doesn't remove the `svn:externals` property, it merely prevents Subversion from acting upon that property when you do an `svn co` or an `svn update`.

If it's any consolation, you can recursively delete properties by using the `-R` flag:

```
$ svn propdel -R svn:externals destdir
```

By the way, are you doing this on your working copy directory, or on the URL?

Comment: Am doing this on the URL .. sourcepath and destpath are URLs

Comment: So, all Subversion is creating upon a merge is a link from your sourcepath to your destpath. You have to delete the property after your merge. You can do a checkout with the `--ignore-externals` parameter, so you don't have the externals, then delete the property from `destpath`.

Answer (score 1):

Probably there's not a single command. Probably need to remove `svn:externals` property afterwards with `svn propdel`. Alternative would be to copy all the files in the folder instead of copying the folder.

Answer (score 0):

svn export --ignore-externals should do it.