# Effect of --ignore-externals on svn copy

Tags: svn

I am struggling to understand the purpose of the `--ignore-externals` option for the `svn copy`command.

I do understand that is does not delete the `svn:external`property from the copied item as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22495255/3809520).

So I created a basic test scenario where I have a repository with a file and a directory. The directory has a external property to pull an older version of the file. Copying the folder with `svn copy`with or without `--ignore-externals` seems to do the same thing... Both times the copied folder has the copied property (as expected). So where is the difference?

From [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28375749/3809520) it seems that the option has only an effect when working locally.

Could some please explain this?